# Discord.js V13 sending a message to a specific channel of a specific guild

Tags: node.js, discord.js, bots

I'm failing to achieve something very simple. I can't send a message to a specific channel of a specific guild. I've browsed through the documentation and similar threads on stack overflow.

```js
const guild = client.guilds.cache.find(g => g.id === process.env.guildId)
const channel = guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === "log-channel")
channel.send('')
```

Does not work. Instead, I'm getting this error:

```
const channel = guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === "log-channel")
                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'channels')
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Seems like `guild` is undefined. Make sure it is in the cache and that `process.env.guildId` is the correct ID.

Comment: @Jakye `process.env.guildId` is correct, so I think that the cache is the problem? I don't really know how to use the cache property since it's not really explained in detail in the docs

Comment: Have you requested the `GUILDS` intent when creating your client? If not, that may be the cause.

Comment: Thank's for posting! Please add the code you used to resolve your problem in your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out what the problem was. I didn't set the GUILDS intent (thanks to Jakye in the comments).